value is not updating inside bottom showModalBottomSheet using bloc
That's my main screen:
 class CreateApplyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateApplyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateApplyScreen> createState() => _CreateApplyScreenState();
}

class _CreateApplyScreenState extends State<CreateApplyScreen> {
  final bloc = CreateApplyBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: BlocProvider<CreateApplyBloc>(
        create: (context) => bloc,
        child: CustomWillPopScope(
          onWillPop: false,
          action: () {},
          child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
              valueListenable: currentPage,
              builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16),
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: _pageController,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: [
                   
                      CreditInfo(
                        bloc: bloc,
                        onCountinue: () {
                          onNavigate();
                        },
                      ),
                    
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

My second screen
class CreditInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  final CreateApplyBloc bloc;
  final Function onCountinue;
  const CreditInfo({super.key, required this.onCountinue, required this.bloc});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<CreateApplyBloc, DataState>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is CreateApplyState) {
            return Column(
          children: [
                CustomTextField(
                  hintText: state.selectedMonth == 0
                      ? AppStrings.select
                      : '${state.selectedMonth} ay',
                  onTap: () {
                    showSuggestedMonths(context, () {},state,bloc);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}

and my bottom modal sheet:
showSuggestedMonths(BuildContext context, Function onTapYes,
    CreateApplyState state, CreateApplyBloc bloc) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => SuggestedMonthsModal(
          onTapYes: onTapYes, state: state, bloc: bloc, ctx: context));
}
class SuggestedMonthsModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTapYes;
  final BuildContext ctx;
  final CreateApplyState state;
  final CreateApplyBloc bloc;

  const SuggestedMonthsModal(
      {super.key,
      required this.onTapYes,
      required this.state,
      required this.ctx,
      required this.bloc});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CreateApplyBloc>(
      create: (context) => CreateApplyBloc(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ModalViewWidget(
            widget: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: state.suggestedMonths.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          BlocProvider.of<CreateApplyBloc>(context).add(SelectMonthEvent(state.suggestedMonths[i]));
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            state.selectedMonth == state.suggestedMonths[i]
                                ? SvgPicture.asset(AppImages.filledRadio)
                                : SvgPicture.asset(AppImages.emptyRadio),
                          
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                     
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

So when I Press
onTap: () {
                              BlocProvider.of<CreateApplyBloc>(context).add(SelectMonthEvent(state.suggestedMonths[i]));
                            },

here to update my code, nothing changes, state is not updating. It is updates only after hot reload. I think problem is somewhere with passing context.(not inside my bloc file or state)  I have already tried everything, but nothing works.

The issue seems to be with the way you are providing your CreateApplyBloc to your widgets. In your SuggestedMonthsModal widget, you are creating a new instance of CreateApplyBloc which is different from the one you passed down from the CreateApplyScreen. This means that any changes in state made in this new bloc will not reflect in the old bloc.
To fix this, you should pass the same instance of the bloc to your SuggestedMonthsModal widget. Here's how you can do it:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CreateApplyBloc>.value(
      value: bloc,
      child: Column( // your code 

also
 InkWell(onTap: () {
         bloc.add(SelectMonthEvent(state.suggestedMonths[i]));
}


Thank you! I tried this one, but my state remains the same

one approach is to wrap the bottom sheet's column widget with a StatefulBuilder widget.
showSuggestedMonths(BuildContext context, Function onTapYes,
CreateApplyState state, CreateApplyBloc bloc) {

showModalBottomSheet(

backgroundColor: Colors.white,
elevation: 0,
isScrollControlled: true,
context: context,
builder: (_) {

  // Wrap the column widget with StatefulBuilder
  return StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return SuggestedMonthsModal(
        onTapYes: onTapYes,
        state: state,
        bloc: bloc,
        ctx: context,
        setState: setState, // Pass the setState function to the modal
      );
    },
  );
},
);
}


I use Bloc in order not to use setState
